# Text appears in a much narrower column on mobile browsers than on desktop, so much so, it's squeezed off the page

Tags: text, mobile-website

I'd be very grateful for any advice on the above issue.

I have tested the site on the major desktop browsers and everything looks fine.

However on opera, on my smart phone, all text is squeezed into a narrow column to the extent that text is overlapping onto other elements. I'm told this is the case on the iPhone as well.

It's as though too much padding is being added to text, but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

I thought perhaps the font size was being increased on the mobile device, but it seems to be in proportion.

One last thought was too many line breaks are being rendered?

N.B everything else looks fine, only the text is being affected

here is a sample page http://www.cajoledesign.co.uk/main%20menu.html

this is the (horrible, I'm sure!) CSS.

```
body {
background:#fff;
font-size:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container {
height:2370px;
width:900px;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
}

a img {
border:0;
}

.style2 {
color:#666;
}

.style3 {
color:#999;
}

.style5 {
font-size:24pt;
}

@font-face {
font-family:TitlingGothicFBSkylineRegul;
src:url(../fonts/TitlingGothicFBSkylineRegul.woff);
}

h1 {
color:#fff;
font:34pt TitlingGothicFBSkylineRegul, arial, Century Gothic, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left:60px;
padding-bottom:15px;
line-height:18px;
letter-spacing:.04em;
}

p.content {
color:#ccc;
font-size:10pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:arial, arial, sans-serif;
line-height:18px;
padding-left:60px;
padding-right:80px;
text-align:left;
}

#background {
height:2370px;
width:900px;
background-image:url(../images/blackbackground.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
position:absolute;
}

#aiologo {
height:209px;
width:170px;
background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
top:0;
}

#phonenumber {
height:50px;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:125px;
}

#mediaiconscontainer {
width:90px;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:180px;
}

#facebookicon {
float:left;
}

#twittericon {
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}

#goodfoodlogo {
position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:120px;
}

img.floatLeft {
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

img.slash {
margin-top:30px;
}

ul#topnav {
width:315px;
list-style:none;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
padding-left:50px;
top:30px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-1 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-2 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat -105px 0;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-3 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat -210px 0;
}

ul#topnav2 {
width:315px;
list-style:none;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:30px;
}

ul#topnav2 li#topnav-1 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#topnav2 li#topnav-2 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav2.png) no-repeat -105px 0;
}

ul#topnav2 li#topnav-3 a {
width:105px;
background:url(../images/nav2.png) no-repeat -210px 0;
}

#menucontainer {
position:absolute;
top:550px;
width:800px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#spielcontainer {
position:absolute;
top:230px;
width:800px;
height:300px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

p.spiel {
color:#ccc;
font-size:11pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:georgia, arial, serif;
line-height:20px;
padding-left:60px;
padding-right:80px;
text-align:left;
}

h2 {
color:#f1731e;
font-size:14pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:arial, arial, serif;
line-height:18px;
padding-left:60px;
padding-right:80px;
text-align:left;
margin-top:30px;
}

h3 {
color:#f1731e;
font-size:16pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:georgia, arial, serif;
line-height:18px;
padding-left:60px;
padding-right:80px;
text-align:left;
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
width:800px;
height:80px;
top:2290px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

ul.footer {
list-style-type:none;
padding-bottom:30px;
margin:0;
}

li.footer {
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:8px;
}

li.footer a {
color:#fff;
font-size:10pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:georgia, arial, serif;
line-height:18px;
}

li.footer a:hover {
color:#f1731e;
font-size:10pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:georgia, arial, serif;
line-height:18px;
}

p.footer {
color:#666;
font-size:8pt;
font-weight:400;
font-family:georgia, arial, serif;
line-height:18px;
text-align:left;
}

ul#topnav li,ul#topnav2 li {
display:inline;
}

ul#topnav li a,ul#topnav2 li a {
height:60px;
float:left;
text-indent:-9999px;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-1 a:hover,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-1 a:hover {
background-position:0 -60px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-1 a.current,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-1 a.current {
background-position:0 -120px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-2 a:hover,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-2 a:hover {
background-position:-105px -60px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-2 a.current,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-2 a.current {
background-position:-105px -120px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-3 a:hover,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-3 a:hover {
background-position:-210px -60px;
}

ul#topnav li#topnav-3 a.current,ul#topnav2 li#topnav-3 a.current {
background-position:-210px -120px;
}
```

Comment: Appears fine for me on both an iPhone 5 and a Blackberry.

Comment: Mr Flocker- Thanks for checking it out on your devices. It suddenly occured to me there must be emulators to check this stuff with and I found a tool for doing so. It does look fine on the devices you mention but on others still screwyand I can't figure out a correlation. Below is a screen grab left one is incorrect

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-X3FUq8hxky0/UZKsTHpp5HI/AAAAAAAAAp0/zpBCF8sYZJM/s912/Untitled-1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check out the     `<meta name="viewport" ...` command in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it and it didn't seem to fix it, only prevent zooming.